# Giant Swap File fills hard drive to capacity

Tags: linux, filesystems, swap-file

Today I had a most odd experience on our student computing server.  Suddenly, you could not save a file and you got a "file system full" message.  So I did a `du -sh` on all user directories to see what was happening. I discovered a home directory with nearly 12G in it.

I subsequently entered the home directory and found a swap file of enormous size. I deleted it.  After the deletion, the directory was quite small, under 1M.  What could have caused this to happen? Our network has been pogoing up and down quite a bit recently.

Comment: What do you name a "swap file"? It is for sure not the system swap of the memory management (this one uses a dedicated partition, and for sure does not write anything in a home directory). What was the file name? `vim` creates files with a `.swp` extension when editing files, for example.

Comment: It was an ordinary text file of small size that generated this huge swap file.   This was not generated by the user, it was generated by the system in a moment of malfunction.  It had a .swp extension.  It was far too big to open and it had to be removed, as the file system was in vapor lock.

Comment: You might consider using disk quotas to prevent a single user filling the disk. I started using that on our server years ago because of a similar problem (an error log file growing to the whole disk...).